# Update the Timestamp columnin PostgreSql database

Tags: postgresql

My timestamp: 2018-01-01 00:00:00 in table temp and field temp_date. I want to update to 2018-01-01 18:06:00 by SQL. How can I ?

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the timestamp to a `date` and then add the time you want to set:

```
update temp
  set temp_date = temp_date::date + time '18:06:00'
where ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the date_trunc function to 0 the time portion and make_interval function to create the correct interval to add.

```
 with t (date_temp) as (select now() )
 select date_trunc('day',date_temp) + make_interval(hours => 18, mins => 6)
   from t;
```